# Relay always damaged in switching circuit

Tags: mosfet, switches, power-electronics, electrical, latching-relay

I have a simple relay switching circuit which is used to turn off/on the power supply to a laptop.

SPDT Relay is 8A , 440AC part number--> G2RL-24DC.

The relay always gets get damaged - the contacts do not movr at all.

Either the contacts are permanently closed or common pin is not and at all moving. Can you suggest a solution to resolve the issue? I see no physical damage like coils burned or contacts burned.

A laptop charger with 230V/3A is connected to this relay. I am switching the AC power with the relay

Simple circuit with transistor relay on/off:

[image]

Comment: Try harder to upload pic. Your whole question rests on that info.

Comment: And add a link to the datasheet for the relay into your question.

Comment: The DC rated load for the [G2RL-24DC](https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-g2rl.pdf) may be exceeded because of inrush current when you first make contact. That's just a thought assuming that you have a good relay to start and that you are correct about having "damaged contacts." However, there are myriad ways that your writing could be misinterpreted. So perhaps write more and provide some kind of helpful diagram, as well.

Comment: i have added more details.pls help me. my relay application is AC ouput 230V/3A for laptop charger

Answer (score 3):

You are welding the contacts of the relay by the surge current,  probably caused by capacitance in the power supply front end.

One approach would be to use a physically bigger relay with a better surge current rating. Probably a TV-5 rated relay would be acceptable, though the rating is UL/CSA so it's limited to 120VAC, so make sure the relay itself is rated for your mains (250VAC etc.). See [this](https://www.components.omron.com/relay-basics/general-app#app02) from Omron's data.

[image]

Comment: I'm almost beginning to wonder if hybrid relays should "be a thing" that is readily and widely available for those seeking a nearly bullet-proof relay switch. Sure, this would mean lower stand-off voltages and more leakage. But for many uses by people who just want something to work, it seems like it should be a product (more expensive of course.) The hybrids I've seen around aren't a simple, self-contained module but a board system. But I've not looked all that hard, I suppose. Any thoughts?

Comment: @jonk The idea has been around for at least 35 years, maybe more like 45 if memory serves, parallel a triac with a mechanical relay so you don't need a heatsink and the relay lasts almost indefinitely. There are a number of issues that have caused it to be a market failure pretty much (Omron has an existing G9H series, but they are ~$100 USD each). Relays are cheap, under a dollar for many smaller ones, they last long enough and provide acceptable isolation, and they don't tend to fail suddenly during the warranty period.  One reason I've been reluctant to used them is that the failure 1/2

Comment: 2/2 mode is "on", which is a bad thing in many applications. Triacs are also virtually impossible to protect against switching into a short circuit, you end up using an enormous triac to switch a few amperes. [This](https://i.imgur.com/vzb1GQk.png) circuit appeared in a very old Motorola application note, back when they were printed individually on nice thick white paper. It was reprinted in the SCR databooks later.

Comment: The "on" failure mode is a serious one. And the $100/ea means that the application would have to be highly unusual to justify the cost. Thanks for the thoughts. Appreciated. Hmm. I do see [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/417696/38098) on this site regarding the "fail closed" issue.

Comment: @jonk Last time I considered this I was going to put a fuse in series with the triac so when it failed on the fuse would eventually open (the load was reasonably well known) and the remainder of the mechanical relay life would take over. That presupposes the relay is actually capable of reliably switching the load, sans triac, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You need relays with more robust contacts for a reactive load such as those on the front end of laptop chargers.

[image]

The arc occurs when connected with contact bounce or disconnected with an inductive filter and storage cap to filter RF.  The down side is the surge current derating on silver oxide contacts is HUGE often from 10A to 0.3A for miniature and 10A to 5A for larger ones like this.

[image]

Although a carefully-designed RC-snubber would bypass the damaging high temp arc currents that burn the contacts, without design specs on your charger, one can only guess.

Plug in your charger into a wall socket slowly at night and see the arc for yourself. Which one is bigger? Connection or disconnect? The random phase will give random results.

p.s. I just noticed the SPDT contacts are even worse rated for surge current at 300V which is what you show in the schematic.

Comment: Even Japanese can miss finger errors of sensitibity.